# iPhone - MPMoviePlayerController : sample code demonstrating two problems

Tags: iphone, ipad

This is a sample code involving MPMoviePlayerController that shows two problems:

**FIRST PROBLEM - Controller vanishing**
To see this first problem

1. Run the project on an iPad.
2. select a video from the iPad library
3. try to play it. The controller will vanish forever.

**SECOND PROBLEM - Controller Crash**

1. uncomment the line "[self createThumbnails];" (line 190)
2. run the app again on iPad
3. select a video

This method you have uncommented will create asynchronous thumbnails for the video and this will make the app crash. As far as I have tried to use this in the past, this  method *requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:allThumbnails timeOption:* never worked for videos picked from the library using the UIImagePickerController.

I am banging my head in the wall for days and I have no clue on how to solve that.

Please give it a try.

The code is here (this is an iPad project):
http://www.mediafire.com/?6i4dm3a6gs888ci

I hope you guys can figure out why this happens.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you also let us know what kind of crash it is?  I will have an iPad tomorrow but cannot test right now on the actual device...

Comment: I think the project works on the simulator. The project demonstrates two problems: 1) the control vanishes when you press play 2) the application crashes due to a problem inside the framework (no way to fix that... apple is the one that can fix, and this second bug is around since iOS 3.x... yes, I have reported then).

Comment: I could reproduce both problems on my ipad, the vanishing movie player and the crash during creation of thumbnails, but have still no explanation.

Comment: Both problems also occur, when the content url of the MPMoviePlayerController is set to a remote http url.

Comment: this MPMoviePlayerController is the most crappy controller ever written by Apple. I am having problems with this since iOS 3.1.3... please let me know if you discover something. I am desperate. :(

Comment: I haven't given up on this yet.  I'm going to put it on my iPad tomorrow on a plane trip and see if I can't hammer it out.

Comment: thanks!!! I will post any solution if I find one. These problems are disgusting.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but I just finished writing an app that was generating thumbnails in bulk and triggering strange crashes, so it may be related to your second problem.

Here's what I tried, and one of these fixed it:

- create a new MPMoviePlayerController for every movie I needed a thumb of. Use and discard.
- after getting the thumbnail back in the notification, call **stop** on the MPMoviePlayerController before releasing it.

In general, discarding or recycling MPMoviePlayerControllers while still playing seems dangerous. No idea on the UIImagePickerController interactions though, sorry.

Comment: but why did you do that if you can generate synchronous thumbnails with "[player thumbnailImageAtTime:aTime timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];"? This method works fine. No need to all this herculean work you are doing. The crash occurs  with the asynchronous method "requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:". This is the one I mention on #2...

Comment: There were other reasons, mainly that: I couldn't block the main thread; and if I tried this en masse, the request for the second thumbnail would block. Collecting async thumbs from the notification wasn't a big deal and it worked, so I decided not to look deeper while on the clock.